# RIP Michael F. Flynn

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Author [Michael F. Flynn](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/flynn_michael_f), most notable for the [*Firestar*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?13361) sequence of novels, passed away at the very end of September.  Flynn got his start publishing short works mostly in *Analog* in the mid-1980s, working up to the serialized novel [*In the Country of the Blind*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1724) (serialized 1987, novel 1990) in which Babbage's Difference Engine worked and is used by a secret organization to manipulate the course of history.  (Scooping the 1990 Sterling/Gibson collaboration *The Difference Engine* by several years.)  His early novella "[Eifelheim](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48638)" (1986) was nominated for a Hugo Award, placing 5th.

[image: Cover of Analog, August 1987 showing a bespectacled Victorian gentleman, in a Victorian-appearing streetscape, holding a stick from which modern inventions like jet airplanes, cars, and computers dangle from strings like a marionette]